# Element wise addition of three list within an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, addition

Suppose I have this array,

```
arr = [[7, 6], [4, 2, 7],[4,4,6,2]]
```

and I want to get a new list like this,

```
list = [15,12,13,2]
```

how can I get it? I am using the following method but it is not working:

```
list = np.sum(arr, axis=0)
```

Comment: You input is a python list, not a numpy array. Should the `10` be a `12`?

Comment: your input is a Python list, and the dimension is mismatched

Comment: Just a suggestion, avoid naming variables python keywords, such as `list`.

Comment: 'not working' is a meaningless phrase on SO - might  even say 'bad language'.  Show the actual error and how you tried to learn from it.  Show how the desired result works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

arr = [[7, 6], [4, 2, 7],[4,4,6,2]]

out = list(map(sum, zip_longest(*arr, fillvalue=0)))
```

Output: `[15, 12, 13, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `numpy` padding ([`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)):

```
a = [[7, 6], [4, 2, 7], [4,4,6,2]]
width = np.max([len(x) for x in a])
np.stack([np.pad(x, (0, width-len(x)), constant_values=0)
         for x in a]).sum(axis=0).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[15, 12, 13, 2]
```